# Nuxt + Vuex mapGetters value is always undefined

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm using **VueX with Nuxt.JS** so let's suppose the following code in the file `store/search.js`:

```
    export const state = () => ({
    results: null
});

export const mutations = {
    setResults(state, { results }) {
        state.results = results;
    }
};

export const actions = {
    startSearch({ commit, dispatch }, { type, filters }) {
        commit("setResults", { type, filters });
    }
};

export const getters = {
    results: state => state.results
};
```

Now in my component `results.vue`, under the computed property I have something like this:

```
<template>
<button @click="handleSearch">Search</button>
<div v-if="results && results.length" class="results" >
<div v-for="item in results" :key="item.id">

          {{item}}

        </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>

import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";
 data() {
    return {
      selected_type: null,
      filters: null
    };
  },
methods: {
    setType(type) {
      this.selected_type = type;
      this.handleSearch();
    },
    setFilters(filters) {
      this.filters = filters;
    },
    handleSearch() {
      this.startSearch({ type: this.selected_type, filters: this.filters });
    },
    ...mapActions("search", {
      startSearch: "startSearch"
    })
  },
computed: {
...mapGetters("search", {
      results: "results"
    })
}
</script>
```

My question is: why the `item` in the for loop (in the template section) always return **undefined** ?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I found it:
in computed should be an array, not an object so:

```
...mapGetters("search", [
      "results"
]

// Now results is populated.
```